# Why is there a 404 on page 2+ for my search page?

Tags: url-rewriting, search, rewrite-rules, 404-error

I've overridden the search.php template from within a plugin, and I've replaced the global `$wp_query` with a different one, and without any paging parameters it works fine.

Once I add a `/page/2/` on there so that it looks like `/page/2/?s=foo` it gives me a 404.

I'm guessing this is some kind of rewrite issue.

I've tried changing the permalink structure to plain, and changing the pagination links to look like: `/?paged=2&s=foo` but that also gives me a 404.

Comment: Then the problem is likely with the `$wp_query` you used in placed of the default one. On the `/page/2` page, `echo $wp_query->request` and check the SQL query.

Comment: I think it's a rewrite issue

Comment: But if you've disabled permalinks (i.e. "pretty" links) and you're still getting 404, then it's not supposed to be a rewrite issue.

Comment: You can't paginate beyond the number of pages in the main query. Use `pre_get_posts` to alter the main query before it's run rather than replacing `$wp_query`.

Comment: I would prefer to avoid using pre_get_posts. I already have some code that builds a WP_Query object. Is there a way to make the pre_get_posts query the same as this other query object?

Comment: I believe you could achieve the same query via the `pre_get_posts` filter - or one of the many other filters, e.g. `posts_clauses`.

Comment: I can't print out the `$wp_query` object or the `request` property when `/page/2/` is applied. The template where this code exists doesn't get executed. So I don't think I'll be able to inspect any properties of `$wp_query`.

Comment: I think I fixed the issue. I ended up using `page` as a parameter instead of `paged`. e.g. `/?s=foo&page=2` I'm guessing the query var has to be named `page` when you're dealing with the general site search, although I have no idea why it wasn't working when the URL structure looked like `/page/2/?s=foo`

Comment: Maaaybe you're using a custom Page as the endpoint for search results. Or maybe a plugin (or the active theme) is doing that. Hence `page` is expected over `paged`, and `/page/2` doesn't work maybe because of the lack of the proper URL rewrite or custom code that will make `/page/{n}` works.